# Running android development app on real device?

Tags: android, debugging

I usually develop in .NET using Visual Studio. I'm just trying to build my first (Hello Work) android App. So I'm new to Eclipse and new to Android.

I followed everything on this link up to
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
Up to "Run on a real device".
I've got a Galaxy S4 connected to the USB and Developer options > USB Debugging activated.

But Eclipse doesn't seem to see the Android USB Device.

(I know I still have the option to create a virtual device, but I'd like this to work too.)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you installed the drivers http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Download Samsung Kies and install the USB drivers.

Comment: this is because you didn't install ADB driver for your S4, follow this link and you should be able to debug it the same way you debug on emulator. http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html and this 
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Comment: Thank you, for now I stuck on there http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7 step 3: I can't find "Diveces" but "Device Manager". In there, I don't have "Other device" mentionned on step 4 and so far I can find the smartphone in the devices.

Comment: Found it in the "Portable Devices". But now installing the driver from <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\, it says that the folder doesn't contains a driver for x64-base systems.

Comment: I have now installed Kies too and the device turned into "SAMSUNG Android ADB interface" but Android sees a device identified by a Serial Number, AVD Name : N/A, Taget: unknown, Debug:"", State : Offline

Comment: Ok, actually this display a message on the mobile screen and I had to push OK to give the computer the access to the mobile device. Now it works.